# WPF Customize TabControl to popup TabItems as Windows with double click

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, popupwindow, tabitem

I would like to customize the default **TabControl** so that if the user double-clicks the **header** of a **TabItem**, that **TabItem** is pop up like a **Window**.

I have already found a way to do this by registering a handler for the **DoubleClick** event on **TabItem** **Header** using style. And in the code-behind, detach the **TabItem** from the original **TabControl** and add it to another **TabControl** on Popup **Window**.

Now I want to inherit **TabControl** class and use Style/ Template and Code-behind of this class to encapsulate the behavior into the new class. 
How can I do that?

Comment: use `CustomControl` https://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html

Comment: You already got the answer. Inherit from TabControl, define a template for it. Good luck.

Comment: I posted another question about this inheritance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193150/wpf-inherit-tabcontrol-and-customize-the-style